# Reversing a string in Java - Giving error

Tags: java, string, char, reverse

I created a method for reversing a string input but it keeps giving me error and telling me to change the method return type to char. Dont understand why. Anyone know how to fix this? Ill include screenshot of error

```
public String reverse(String text) {
    String reverse = " ";
    for(int i = text.length() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse = text.charAt(i);
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Comment: Function `CharAt` returns a `char`, not a `String`! Let alone the fact that you are attempting to reassign a new value into the `reverse` variable at every iteration, which is pretty nonsense even regardless of your specific purpose, as it would only attain the last value assigned to it!!!

Comment: Don't post images when text suffices.

Answer (score 1):

You have to concat the chars together:

```
public static String reverse(String text) {
    String reverse = "";
    for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse += text.charAt(i);
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

You can also use

```
public static String reverse(String text) {
    return new StringBuilder(text).reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: `reverse` will be over-written at every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
public String reverse(String text) {
    String reverse = "";
    for (int i = text.length() -1; i >=0; i--) {
        reverse+=text.charAt(i);
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because [`charAt(index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) basically returns the `char` value at the specified index.

In your code `text.charAt(i)` is returning you the `char` value and you're assigning it to `String`.

Instead, you can use:

```
reverse += String.valueOf(text.charAt(i));
```

---

*FYI: You can also reverse your String `text` with this one line code:*

```
new StringBuilder(text).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reverse a String using recursion this way

```
String reverse(String str){
    return (str.length()==1)?str:reverse(str.subString(str,1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works well..

```
    public class reversestring {
    public static String reversestring(String string) {
        String reverse = new StringBuffer(string).
        reverse().toString();
        return reverse;
        }      
    public static void main(String[] args){
              String string="abcdef";
              System.out.println("String after reverse:" +reversestring(string));
           }
        }
```

> **String after reverse: fedcba**

This should help..

Now answering your specific doubt..

> The java string charAt() method returns a char value at the given
>   index number. The index number starts from 0.

**Example**

```
public class Solution{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
String name="StackExchange";  
char ch=name.charAt(4);//returns the char value at the 4th index  
System.out.println(ch);  
}}
```

The output is ***k*** ..

This is how charAt() works. You cant expect it to return strings.

Happy learning !

Answer (score 0):

You have done a great job, is only a small mistake in for loop. you just have to add every char back to the reserve string not to reassign als @barakmanos emphasised already , you code is perfect just make this little change and it will be fine.

change this -->> `reverse = text.charAt(i);`

to this ----->>>> `reverse += text.charAt(i);`

just keep adding the chars back to the reserve not to assign to the String
because you cannot convert the char to the string by assigning the char to the string.